# Reading a large number of files without hardcoding their path

Tags: java, text, filepath

This may be more of a "best practices" kind of question, but I am attempting to use two text documents in my current project and am unsure of the best way to proceed in reading and/or storing them. I currently have paths to them hard coded into my filereader, which is definitely not what I want (below for current implementation).

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\e\\t\\c\\.\\text.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            string1 = string1 + " " + line;
        }
    }
```

This works, but I would have to change the file location for each computer that used it.

What I've tried:

- Hard coding the file path (works, not at all flexible)
- Creating a local filepath through my project (I ran into some difficulties and couldn't figure this out)
- Copy/paste the several thousand word text files directly into strings in my program (seems really ugly, but I'm not sure if that's something that should /shouldn't be done)

I'm still pretty new with Java and programming in general, so please let me know if you need more information or if there's anything else I should put up (or if there's a similar question that I missed in my search). Thank you all!

EDIT:

On the functionality of my program: what I am doing is taking a string that a user types and then checking that against a the text documents I am attempting to upload to see how many match (similar to using "ctrl+f" for every indiviudal word you are attempting to find in a page/document, where the page/document is the library of words I am attempting to upload).

I had to take a short break, but I'm going to try your suggestions now. These all look great and many thanks!

Comment: these files contains some words that you want to use into your app or something more special?

Comment: @Kean Don't forget to come back and accept an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding internal resources (the text files in your application are internal resources if they are provided as part of the application), a project typically decides what the directory structure is going to be. Generally, in a project there will be "src/" directory where the source code is and under "src/" you can place a folder called "res/" for your resources. To avoid resource names clashing you can further specify package name like structures. So if your class has package com.example.*, then you can place text.txt in res/com/example/ Now in your class responsible for reading in the resources you can have:

```
try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/com/example/text.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            string1 = string1 + " " + line;
        }
}
```

However, if the text files must be provided by the user system then they are external resources and in this case the path to them must be provided at runtime. Generally, as arguments to the program itself. So in your `main()` method capture the path to the file as follows:

```
String fileName = args[0]; // assuming the user has provided arguments

try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            string1 = string1 + " " + line;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is most similar to the solution I wound up with. The only real difference is instead of getClass() I used WhateverClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file/location/relative/to/WhateverClass/here"); I'm sure if I spent more time I could do just that with the other answers, but I'm on a bit of a time crunch. Thank you!

Comment: It is not good practice to place resources in a generic directory like "/res/test.txt", because it carries a risk of collision in an application that uses many libraries.  They should be placed in a package-like directory, then retrieved by passing a *relative* path to Class.getResourceAsStream.  For instance, if the class reading the resources is `com.example.MyApp`, the resource should be placed at src/res/com/example/test.txt and should be read using `WhateverClass.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt")`.

Comment: Yes, a very good point. Please see updated version of the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put the files is a resource folder of your app, and use them like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("test.txt").getFile());
```

If there is an entire bounch of files in resources, you can use getResources(""); to browse for all resources in your app and select the one being your text files. ie place them in a special folder, so discriminating them would be easyer.

Comment: While this removes the hardcoding of the path, it still requires hardcoding of the file names.

Comment: @ChetanKinger if you use this in resource folder, it becames actually part of your app, so hardcoding the name is not such an issue.

Comment: Hardcoding the names of thousand files is really an issue IMO. It has no real advantage from the point of view of solving this problem since all you are doing is shortening the `String` that gets hardcoded.

Comment: @ChetanKinger sorry for m,issing the point you have a lot of file, what about enumerating resourecs?

Comment: Not a problem. Developers are not always on the same page with each other :). I am not sure what you mean by enumerating resources. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @FelicePollano What exactly am I getting the class of for getClass()? Am I referencing a generic string/file/other type of object?

Comment: @Kean is just a shortcut to have the current class loader. Class executing your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There have been many good suggestions, but nobody has mentioned environment variables or system properties. You can define an environment variable for your OS and get it like this:

```
String configPath = System.getenv("CONFIG_PATH");
```

Or you can pass the application a system variable when you start it up:

```
java -jar app.jar -DconfigPath="/home/..."
```

Then use it in the code:

```
String configPath = System.getProperty("configPath");
```